# I don't think "be something to doing" grammatically correct

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Is "be something to be doing" grammatically correct?

From this [book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=M64sDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA4&lpg=PA4&dq=What%20have%20been%20the%20impediments%20to%20realizing%20the%20full%20potential%20of%20medical%20imaging%20CAD?%20There%20have%20been%20a%20number%20of%20difficulties.&source=bl&ots=gNQLABN2di&sig=ACfU3U0MgpNkz51jAkzJ7HVo2eUuGdBnNw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI-o2b5rvjAhVOB50JHaKWBAAQ6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=What%20have%20been%20the%20impediments%20to%20realizing%20the%20full%20potential%20of%20medical%20imaging%20CAD%3F%20There%20have%20been%20a%20number%20of%20difficulties.&f=false) "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing"

> What have been the **impediments to realizing** the full potential of
>   medical imaging CAD? There have been a number of difficulties.

Is "the impediments to realizing" grammatically correct? I don't think so, but this is a formally published book by Springer, so I need a double check.

Comment: Your question says, "be something to **be** doing," but there is no second *be* in your quote. The sentence structure used here is: "What is the `noun` to `gerund`".

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I've updated my post. So `noun` to `gerund` 
 here is grammatical and idiomatic, right?

Comment: yaojp: ***The advantage to asking** questions on ELL is that people sometimes give examples that make it easier for you to understand things.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is fine. It might help to look at the structure as:

(What have been) (the impediments) (to realising the full potential) (of...)

I suspect that you are mis-understanding what 'realising' means in this context.